# WCF Datetime problems when empty

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, datetime

I have my class with a data member `Datetime StartDate`.

This value is filled by the database and can be empty. In this case, I do this command :

```
StartDate = new DateTime ()
```

Besides, this property is sent by a WCF service. But, when the `StartDate` is empty (so equal to `01/01/0001`) my client loose the connection with the service.

Should I use another type for WCF (datetimeoffset) ? Or how can I use the `datetime` ?

Thanks  !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a nullable DateTime in your contract:

```
[DataMember]
public Nullable<DateTime> StartDate {get;set;}
```

or

```
[DataMember]
public DateTime? StartDate {get;set;}
```

Comment: OK, but why the MinValue of DateTime don't work with WCF ? :S

Comment: I'm not sure for certain but this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025851/why-can-datetime-minvalue-not-be-serialized-in-timezones-ahead-of-utc

Comment: Also, if you're persisting to a MS SQL Server database, Sql DateTime has a min value of January 1, 1753. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.minvalue.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links, i added ToUniversalTime to my command and it works now :) : it was a serialization problem.