# Cannot get JSON response if DateTime is NULL

Tags: c#, json, wcf, datetime, svc

I have sql database. 
In sql the column type is datetime nullable but in c# entities are defined as only datetime.

If the dateTime is null the response as xml format gives no problem but response as json format gives problem. If I change `datetimes` into `datetime?` response as json format works but it effects other entities in bad way.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: In sql database, datetime nullable you mean allow null in datetime column?

Comment: Yes, it is  allowed to be null.

Comment: How do we know what your other entities are and how are they affected by nullable `datetime` ?

Comment: There is a lot of class and a lot of controls. So I can't write them here. In xml I see the datetime 0001-01-01T00:00:00, when it is null. But in json it gives error. It is my problem.There has to be something about DateTime for [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960682/bad-request-when-making-a-call-to-a-rest-wcf-webservice/21966508#21966508

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the json serializer sends the date as 0001-01-01T00:00:00 UTC which can create problems when you deserialize it from a machine in a timezone ahead of UTC.

Try the solution in this thread and see if its helps:
[Why can DateTime.MinValue not be serialized in timezones ahead of UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025851/why-can-datetime-minvalue-not-be-serialized-in-timezones-ahead-of-utc)